# ASP.NET C# Filter DropDownList based on specific Category of Items from Soap Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu, soap-client

OK... I'm stuck here. Sort of new to C# and consuming web services. I have successfully populated a DropDownList from a SOAP service, but what I really need is to filter that list based on a specific category.

Here's what I have so far:

```
problemReporting.soapClient s = new problemReporting.soapClient();
problemReporting.NullRequest nr = new NullRequest();
problemReporting.ProblemDescription[] getDescList = s.getProblemDescriptionList(nr);

ddlProblem.DataSource = getDescList;
ddlProblem.DataTextField = "description";
ddlProblem.DataValueField = "code";
ddlProblem.DataBind();
```

problemReporting.ProblemDescription contains "category", "description" and "code". How do I set the DataSource to equal getDescList where category = Category1? (There's 4 categories of items. The category will be set by a user selecting a category from the previous page, and that value being pulled from the URL via HttpUtility.UrlDecode.)

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly. Datasource would just be assigned to your collection/array, no matter what it contains. You would need to call s.getProblemDescriptionList() again with your new category from the Drop downs OnChange event. Then dropdown.DataBind() to have it take effect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added a bit more info regarding how the category is being set. I hope that helps clarify things.

Comment: Your on the right track. You could redesign and use 2 web service methods. 1 that will get all your categories and the other will get all items for that category. So on start up/init/onload/etc you can call wsclient.GetCategories() and after that call wsclient.GetItemsForCategory("category1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you do not do this on your SQL (if you are using SQL at all). If you can't I would suggest that you take a look at [LinQ2Entities](http://interactiveasp.net/blogs/natesstuff/archive/2008/11/02/linq-to-entities-example-queries.aspx). Good luck!

Comment: My only data source is the soap service.

Comment: I checked out the "LINQ to Entities Query Example". It worked. Thanks Hanlet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you could filter after the call with `Linq`, but I recommend you change your web service to take a param to filter the results:

```
problemReporting.soapClient s = new problemReporting.soapClient();
problemReporting.NullRequest nr = new NullRequest();
problemReporting.ProblemDescription[] getDescList = s.getProblemDescriptionList(nr);

var cats = from desc in getDescList 
  where desc.category == "Category1"
  select desc;

ddlProblem.DataSource = cats;
ddlProblem.DataTextField = "description";
ddlProblem.DataValueField = "code";
ddlProblem.DataBind();
```

Comment: Had to tweak this a bit to: var catList = from desc in getDescList where desc.category == "Category1" select desc;
It worked though. Thanks Rick.