# ASP.NET C# Filter Data from Soap Service

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, soap-client

I have a Soap service that I added to my .NET project via Service Reference.

```
problemReporting.soapClient s = new problemReporting.soapClient();
problemReporting.NullRequest nr = new NullRequest();
problemReporting.ProblemDescription[] getDescList = s.getProblemDescriptionList(nr);

if (!IsPostBack)
{
      rbProblemList.DataSource = getDescList;
      rbProblemList.DataTextField = "description";
      rbProblemList.DataValueField = "code";
      rbProblemList.DataBind();
}
```

This returns a DropDownList of 23 items. (This list could grow in the future.) The service is returning an array of objects, where each object contains Category, Code, and Description.

How can I create a separate method that will return ONLY the 4 categories that exists in this array? I am unable to find any examples of how to create a method that will filter the data from a soap service.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Do want to return only 4 fixed four categories all the time out of 23 items?

Comment: For now, there are only 4 distinct categories within the 23 items. In the future, they could add more items and/or categories.

Comment: Use a LINQ query to return on the categories you wanted. You would need to maintain the list categories you wanted to return in a flexible manner so that you don't have change the code just for returning a new filtered category.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same code from another question you asked:

[ASP.NET C# Filter DropDownList based on specific Category of Items from Soap Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300414/asp-net-c-sharp-filter-dropdownlist-based-on-specific-category-of-items-from-soa/8300478#8300478)

```
problemReporting.soapClient s = new problemReporting.soapClient();
problemReporting.NullRequest nr = new NullRequest();
problemReporting.ProblemDescription[] getDescList = s.getProblemDescriptionList(nr);

List<string> categories = new List<string>();
categories.Add("Category1");
categories.Add("Category2");
categories.Add("Category3");

var filteredResults = FilterCategories(categories, getDescList);

if (!IsPostBack)
{
      rbProblemList.DataSource = filteredResults;
      rbProblemList.DataTextField = "description";
      rbProblemList.DataValueField = "code";
      rbProblemList.DataBind();
}

public ProblemDescription[] FilterCategories(List<string> categories, ProblemDescription[] data )
{ 
    var cats = from desc in data 
      where categories.Contains(desc.category)
      select desc;

    return cats;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rick. Yes, I'm working on the same thing. I thought I would be able to figure out how to filter the data from the service to get just the categories, but I'm having a hard time at it. The only examples I can find are creating an array by hard coding the values, like you demonstrate.

What I can't figure out is how to extract the category names that the service is providing, so that I can grab the items from what ever category I specify. I've seen the List<> being used, but not with consuming a web service.

Comment: What don't you have different web service methods that filter on the backend?

Comment: Wouldn't that be nice, but unfortunately not. I've been given this one service and have been trying to figure out how to filter out the categories on my end.